# How to generate incremental sub_id not unique using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

My goal is to create a random **id** and an incremental **sub_id** you will find more detailed explanation of my problem below.

**initial dataframe**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
                            (1, 110, 'aaa', 'walk', 'work'),
                            (2, 110, 'aaa', 'walk', 'work'),
                            (3, 110, 'aaa', 'bus', 'work'),
                            (4, 110, 'aaa', 'bus', 'work'),
                            (5, 110, 'aaa', 'walk','work'),
                            (6, 110, 'bbb', 'walk', 'home'),
                            (7, 110, 'bbb', 'bus', 'home'),
                            (8, 110, 'bbb', 'bus',  'home'),
                            (9, 110, 'bbb', 'walk', 'home')
                        ],
                        ['idx', 'u_uuid', 'p_uuid', 'mode', 'dest']
                    )

df.show()

+---+------+------+----+----+
|idx|u_uuid|p_uuid|mode|dest|
+---+------+------+----+----+
|  1|   110|   aaa|walk|work|
|  2|   110|   aaa|walk|work|
|  3|   110|   aaa| bus|work|
|  4|   110|   aaa| bus|work|
|  5|   110|   aaa|walk|work|
|  6|   110|   bbb|walk|home|
|  7|   110|   bbb| bus|home|
|  8|   110|   bbb| bus|home|
|  9|   110|   bbb|walk|home|
+---+------+------+----+----+
```

To generate **trip_id (Can be random)** column I used:

```
df_trip = df.withColumn("trip_id", F.rank().over(Window.orderBy('u_uuid', 'p_uuid', 'dest'))).sort('idx')

+---+------+------+----+----+-------+
|idx|u_uuid|p_uuid|mode|dest|trip_id|
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+
|  1|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|
|  2|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|
|  3|   110|   aaa| bus|work|      1|
|  4|   110|   aaa| bus|work|      1|
|  5|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|
|  6|   110|   bbb|walk|home|      6|
|  7|   110|   bbb| bus|home|      6|
|  8|   110|   bbb| bus|home|      6|
|  9|   110|   bbb|walk|home|      6|
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+
```

To generate **subtrip_id** for each **trip_id**, I used:

```
df_subtrip = df_trip.withColumn("subtrip_id", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(['p_uuid', 'u_uuid', 'dest', 'mode']).orderBy('idx')))

+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+
|idx|u_uuid|p_uuid|mode|dest|trip_id|subtrip_id|
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+
|  1|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|       122|
|  2|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|       122|
|  3|   110|   aaa| bus|work|      1|       123|
|  4|   110|   aaa| bus|work|      1|       123|
|  5|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|       124|
|  6|   110|   bbb|walk|home|      6|       997|
|  7|   110|   bbb| bus|home|      6|       998|
|  8|   110|   bbb| bus|home|      6|       998|
|  9|   110|   bbb|walk|home|      6|       999|
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+
```

Oops!! this isn't what i'm looking for, the problem is that I couldn't create a **sub_id** incremntale like.

**What I m looking for:**

```
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+
|idx|u_uuid|p_uuid|mode|dest|trip_id|subtrip_id|
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+
|  1|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|         1|
|  2|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|         1|
|  3|   110|   aaa| bus|work|      1|         2|
|  4|   110|   aaa| bus|work|      1|         2|
|  5|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|         3|
|  6|   110|   bbb|walk|home|      6|         1|
|  7|   110|   bbb| bus|home|      6|         2|
|  8|   110|   bbb| bus|home|      6|         2|
|  9|   110|   bbb|walk|home|      6|         3|
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Will scala code using standard spark function work for you? You can use equivalent pyspark function.

Comment: Yes sure, I'll try

Comment: Does idx=5 get a different subtrip_id as idx=1 and idx=2 because the previous row has a different mode? A new row with `10 | 110 | aaa | bus | work|` would get 4 as a subtrip_id?

Comment: Yes, exactly 10 | 110 | aaa | bus | work| and 11 | 110 | aaa | bus | work| would 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently not considering the `mode` value of the previous row in your `df_subtrip` statement and I also think that your trip_id statement can cause an OOM exception as all your data is loaded to one partition. Please have a look at the commented example below:

```py
import sys
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([
                            (1, 110, 'aaa', 'walk', 'work'),
                            (2, 110, 'aaa', 'walk', 'work'),
                            (3, 110, 'aaa', 'bus', 'work'),
                            (4, 110, 'aaa', 'bus', 'work'),
                            (5, 110, 'aaa', 'walk','work'),
                            (6, 110, 'bbb', 'walk', 'home'),
                            (7, 110, 'bbb', 'bus', 'home'),
                            (8, 110, 'bbb', 'bus',  'home'),
                            (9, 110, 'bbb', 'walk', 'home')
                        ],
                        ['idx', 'u_uuid', 'p_uuid', 'mode', 'dest']
                    )

df.show()

#your trip_id statement will load all your data to one partition which isn't recommend and can cause OOM
#df_trip = df.withColumn("trip_id", F.rank().over(Window.orderBy('u_uuid', 'p_uuid', 'dest')))
#the following could(!) increase the performance
df = df.repartition('u_uuid', 'p_uuid', 'dest')
df_trip = df.withColumn("trip_id", F.spark_partition_id())

df_trip.show()

defaultW = Window.partitionBy('u_uuid', 'p_uuid', 'dest').orderBy('idx')

#mark the first row of each group with 1
df_subtrip = df_trip.withColumn("subtrip_id", F.when(df_trip.mode != F.lag(df_trip.mode, default='SOMETHING').over(defaultW), 1).otherwise(None))

#gives each first row of a group a row_number
df_subtrip = df_subtrip.withColumn("subtrip_id", F.when(df_subtrip.subtrip_id == 1 , F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('u_uuid', 'p_uuid', 'dest', 'subtrip_id' ).orderBy('idx'))).otherwise(None))

#forward-fill the empty subtrip_id's
df_subtrip = df_subtrip.withColumn('subtrip_id', F.last('subtrip_id', True).over(defaultW.rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize,0)))

df_subtrip.sort('idx').show()
```

Output:

```py
+---+------+------+----+----+
|idx|u_uuid|p_uuid|mode|dest|
+---+------+------+----+----+
|  1|   110|   aaa|walk|work|
|  2|   110|   aaa|walk|work|
|  3|   110|   aaa| bus|work|
|  4|   110|   aaa| bus|work|
|  5|   110|   aaa|walk|work|
|  6|   110|   bbb|walk|home|
|  7|   110|   bbb| bus|home|
|  8|   110|   bbb| bus|home|
|  9|   110|   bbb|walk|home|
+---+------+------+----+----+

+---+------+------+----+----+-------+
|idx|u_uuid|p_uuid|mode|dest|trip_id|
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+
|  5|   110|   aaa|walk|work|     43|
|  1|   110|   aaa|walk|work|     43|
|  2|   110|   aaa|walk|work|     43|
|  3|   110|   aaa| bus|work|     43|
|  4|   110|   aaa| bus|work|     43|
|  6|   110|   bbb|walk|home|     62|
|  7|   110|   bbb| bus|home|     62|
|  8|   110|   bbb| bus|home|     62|
|  9|   110|   bbb|walk|home|     62|
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+

+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+
|idx|u_uuid|p_uuid|mode|dest|trip_id|subtrip_id|
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+
|  1|   110|   aaa|walk|work|     43|         1|
|  2|   110|   aaa|walk|work|     43|         1|
|  3|   110|   aaa| bus|work|     43|         2|
|  4|   110|   aaa| bus|work|     43|         2|
|  5|   110|   aaa|walk|work|     43|         3|
|  6|   110|   bbb|walk|home|     62|         1|
|  7|   110|   bbb| bus|home|     62|         2|
|  8|   110|   bbb| bus|home|     62|         2|
|  9|   110|   bbb|walk|home|     62|         3|
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you, use a loop for an large dataset (10G)  is not recommended maybe use a lambda instead

Comment: This loop isn't looping the rows of your dataframe and the number of iterations is determined by the biggest group of consecutive rows with the same values for `u_uuid`, `p_uuid`, `dest` and `mode`. What worries me more is the `trip_id` because your data will be loaded to one parition. Is it neccesary that `trip_id` is consecutive?

Comment: I have another suggestion, is to suppose that we have a unique id column and we want non unique `+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+`
`|idx|u_uuid|p_uuid|mode|dest|trip_id|subtrip_id|`
`+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+`
`|  1|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|       122|`
`|  2|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|       122|`
`|  3|   110|   aaa| bus|work|      1|       123|`
`|  4|   110|   aaa| bus|work|      1|       123|`
`|  5|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|       124|`
`+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+`

Comment: It will be more readable if you add this to your initial question and explain what you have and what you want like you already did.

Comment: Is not neccesary that trip_id is consecutive but subtrip_id yes

Comment: Thank you, works fine. For the loop on the last line is too slow, I found a simpler and faster way is to make a an Fill Forward on subtrip_id column:)

Answer (score 4):

As an optimization to cronoik's response, you can leverage the fact that you already have a global unique 'idx' column on your dataset and set your 'trip_id' and 'subtrip_id' as the idx of the row where the trip or substrip starts.

This would let you generate the trip_id and subtrip_id with a single pass with monotoniically increasing integers. 
Since you need the subtrip_id to start with 1 and increase by increment of 1, you'll a second window pass :

```
import sys
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([
                            (1, 110, 'aaa', 'walk', 'work'),
                            (2, 110, 'aaa', 'walk', 'work'),
                            (3, 110, 'aaa', 'bus', 'work'),
                            (4, 110, 'aaa', 'bus', 'work'),
                            (5, 110, 'aaa', 'walk','work'),
                            (6, 110, 'bbb', 'walk', 'home'),
                            (7, 110, 'bbb', 'bus', 'home'),
                            (8, 110, 'bbb', 'bus',  'home'),
                            (9, 110, 'bbb', 'walk', 'home')
                        ],
                        ['idx', 'u_uuid', 'p_uuid', 'mode', 'dest']
                    )

tripW = Window.partitionBy('u_uuid', 'p_uuid', 'dest').orderBy('idx')

df_final  = df\
  .withColumn("trip_id", F.first('idx').over(tripW))\
  .withColumn('lagged_mode', F.lag('mode', default='').over(tripW))\
  .withColumn('subtrip_id', (F.col('mode') != F.col('lagged_mode')).cast('int'))\
  .withColumn('subtrip_id',F.sum('subtrip_id').over(tripW))\
  .drop('lagged_mode')\
  .sort('idx')

df_final.show()

+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+
|idx|u_uuid|p_uuid|mode|dest|trip_id|subtrip_id|
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+
|  1|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|         1|
|  2|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|         1|
|  3|   110|   aaa| bus|work|      1|         2|
|  4|   110|   aaa| bus|work|      1|         2|
|  5|   110|   aaa|walk|work|      1|         3|
|  6|   110|   bbb|walk|home|      6|         1|
|  7|   110|   bbb| bus|home|      6|         2|
|  8|   110|   bbb| bus|home|      6|         2|
|  9|   110|   bbb|walk|home|      6|         3|
+---+------+------+----+----+-------+----------+
```

If you look at the generated plan, Spark can build it quite efficiently:

```
df_final.explain()

TakeOrderedAndProject(limit=21, orderBy=[idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST], output=[idx#12637,u_uuid#12638,p_uuid#2863,mode#2864,dest#2865,trip_id#12642,subtrip_id#12643])
+- *(3) Project [idx#2861L, u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, mode#2864, dest#2865, trip_id#12589L, subtrip_id#12614L]
   +- Window [sum(cast(subtrip_id#12604 as bigint)) windowspecdefinition(u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865, idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS subtrip_id#12614L], [u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865], [idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST]
      +- *(2) Project [idx#2861L, u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, mode#2864, dest#2865, trip_id#12589L, cast(NOT (mode#2864 = lagged_mode#12596) as int) AS subtrip_id#12604]
         +- Window [first(idx#2861L, false) windowspecdefinition(u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865, idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS trip_id#12589L, lag(mode#2864, 1, ) windowspecdefinition(u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865, idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS lagged_mode#12596], [u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865], [idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST]
            +- *(1) Sort [u_uuid#2862L ASC NULLS FIRST, p_uuid#2863 ASC NULLS FIRST, dest#2865 ASC NULLS FIRST, idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865, 200)
                  +- Scan ExistingRDD[idx#2861L,u_uuid#2862L,p_uuid#2863,mode#2864,dest#2865]
```

cronoik's solution uses different sort or window criteria and thus will take more expensive sort steps and longer execution time:

```
df_subtrip.sort('idx').explain()

TakeOrderedAndProject(limit=21, orderBy=[idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST], output=[idx#2948,u_uuid#2949,p_uuid#2863,mode#2864,dest#2865,trip_id#2953,subtrip_id#2954])
+- *(4) Project [idx#2861L, u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, mode#2864, dest#2865, trip_id#2887, subtrip_id#2933]
   +- Window [last(subtrip_id#2923, true) windowspecdefinition(u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865, idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS subtrip_id#2933], [u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865], [idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST]
      +- *(3) Sort [u_uuid#2862L ASC NULLS FIRST, p_uuid#2863 ASC NULLS FIRST, dest#2865 ASC NULLS FIRST, idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- *(3) Project [idx#2861L, u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, mode#2864, dest#2865, trip_id#2887, CASE WHEN (subtrip_id#2913 = 1) THEN _we0#2924 ELSE null END AS subtrip_id#2923]
            +- Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865, subtrip_id#2913, idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS _we0#2924], [u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865, subtrip_id#2913], [idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST]
               +- *(2) Sort [u_uuid#2862L ASC NULLS FIRST, p_uuid#2863 ASC NULLS FIRST, dest#2865 ASC NULLS FIRST, subtrip_id#2913 ASC NULLS FIRST, idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                  +- *(2) Project [idx#2861L, u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, mode#2864, dest#2865, trip_id#2887, CASE WHEN NOT (mode#2864 = _we0#2914) THEN 1 ELSE null END AS subtrip_id#2913]
                     +- Window [lag(mode#2864, 1, SOMETHING) windowspecdefinition(u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865, idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS _we0#2914], [u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865], [idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST]
                        +- *(1) Sort [u_uuid#2862L ASC NULLS FIRST, p_uuid#2863 ASC NULLS FIRST, dest#2865 ASC NULLS FIRST, idx#2861L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                           +- *(1) Project [idx#2861L, u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, mode#2864, dest#2865, SPARK_PARTITION_ID() AS trip_id#2887]
                              +- Exchange hashpartitioning(u_uuid#2862L, p_uuid#2863, dest#2865, 200)
                                 +- Scan ExistingRDD[idx#2861L,u_uuid#2862L,p_uuid#2863,mode#2864,dest#2865]
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, your solution is optimal (less transformation) but the result (subtrip_id) isn't what we are looking for.

Comment: Ok if you really need your sub_ids to be in sequence starting with 1, I've updated the answer to match this property. You'll need a second window pass but are still avoiding the additional sort operations

Comment: Really nice. This should be the excepted answer. Upvote.